# Hidden popup extending page

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I am using a Jquery lightbox popup type to display data over a page onclick.
Pretty basic: when the popup is not used, its hidden, then visible when a link is clicked.

Problem is when the data is the popup is very long, it stretches the page even when hidden, leaving a bunch of blank space at the bottom of my page.

How do I get hidden popup to not stretch out my page?

Comment: This can happen if `visibility:hidden` is used to hide a pop-up, instead of `display:none`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can solve it with css:
set hight and width and then set `overflow:hidden` or scroll or auto
or
set `display:none`

and with jquery you can hide your element: `$(element).hide()`